# "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.". Postman goes OK with same headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

**Scenario**

- Win10 x64
- VS2013

I'm trying to make a WebRequest, but I'm getting the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Digging into the inner exception, I got:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

The code which does the request is the following:

```
private static Hashtable exec (String method, String uri, Object data, String contentType) {
    Hashtable response;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (API_BASE_URL + uri);

    request.UserAgent = "MercadoPago .NET SDK v"+MP.version; //version resolves to 0.3.4
    request.Accept = MIME_JSON; // application/json
    request.Method = method; //GET
    request.ContentType = contentType; //application/json
    setData (request, data, contentType); //setData in this case does nothing.

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
      HttpWebResponse apiResult = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse (); //Error throws here
      responseBody = new StreamReader (apiResult.GetResponseStream ()).ReadToEnd ();

      response = new Hashtable();
      response["status"] = (int) apiResult.StatusCode;
      response["response"] = JSON.JsonDecode(responseBody);
    } catch (WebException e) {
      Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
    }
}
```

What i've already done:

- Made the request via Console Application and MVC Application controller. Both throws the same exception
- Called the API via Postman with the exact same headers, which brings me the content correctly.

Those requests were working okay via c# about 4 days ago and I suddenly started having issues, but considering the fact that it responds okay for Postman, I can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's Postman's response

[image]

**EDIT:** Did both requests with Fiddler listening. The result for Postman shows a direct request to the API with HTTPS. When trying with my ConsoleApplication, it shows a HTTP request, which makes a tunnel to the API endpoint, port 443.

[image]

The TextView from Fiddler for the tunnel request says the following:

[image]

I noticed the "time" field which refers to a very old date, but i don't know what does it mean.

Comment: I would try running both requests thru a sniffer (for example, Fiddler)  and compare the two to see where they differ.

Comment: @jdigital Gonna try this, thanks for the idea! Any news i'll post here

Comment: @jdigital tried it. Edited my post with relevant information, it shows something about a failed handshake. Don't know what it means. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try changing your app to use https

Comment: @jdigital it is already using https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to include the use of TLS1.2.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 14):

It is kind of bad practice to enable Tls12 like this-

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

In future, if you'd need to use higher version of TLS, you'll have to update your code.

If you are using an older version of .NET, you can simply switch it higher version in which Tls12 is enabled by default.

For example, this simple change in your web.config will enable Tls12 automatically-

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
```

Comment: Does changing the runtime to target v4.6.1 can wreak havoc in any other part of my code? I mean, compatibility issues with frameworks (i'm using MVC5 and Entity framework) and stuff like that

Comment: We recently upgraded the version and worked out smoothly. However every project has a different nature and there are many factors that the upgrade process can affect. So you can always create a copy of your project and test first and if that work, you know what to do :)

Comment: wish I could upvote this more..... using configuration file is totally the correct way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the code below:

```
string url = ""; // url of the endpoint

WebClient client = new WebClient();
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json"); // same as other parameters in the header

var data = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Same thing happening

Answer (score 5):

(As a reference for others who have the same issue)this also might be the result of a [Double Hop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/) issue , where you should pass the credited user along(in the pool) to the passing server or from one Environment to the other , otherwise the user is set to "ANONYMOUS/USER" and you will get a "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Error

Answer (score 0):

i found same error, just mention 
request.UserAgent = "anything u want";